# Wordpress contact-form7 datepicker IE issue with placeholder

Tags: wordpress

I use the contactfor-7 datepicker plugin in wordpress to display the datepicker in the contact-form7,& it show it but the i also use the placeholder in that field where datepicker display.But the Problem is its working fine in all browser but not in the ie 7,8,9 placeholder work fine but the datepicker is also open but undefined value display(calender not display).for the solution i just put that text field value null in ie. The problem is that ie take the placeholder value.the script which show the placehode condition code are below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
  $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
   var input = $(this);
   if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
     input.val(''); 
   }
  })
  $('[placeholder]').blur(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder') ) {
var ver = getInternetExplorerVersion(); 
//getInternetExplorerVersion() is the function to chek the ie browser
    if ( ver> -1 )
    {
      if ( ver== 8.0 )
         input.val('');
      else if ( ver == 7.0 )
          input.val('');
      else if ( ver == 6.0 )
         input.val('');
    }else{
   input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
    }
}
 }).blur();
 $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
  $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
      input.val('');
    }
  })
 });
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if there is any conflict in the Jquery ? maybe you are loading multiple Jquery's ?